# Adding to vectors correctly

Tags: c++, vector

I'm creating a program that puts prime numbers into a vector. I'll give an example to better demonstrate how this program should work:

**User: 3**

**Output 3**

**User: 13**

**Ouput: 3 5 7 11 13**

To put it in words, this program is adding up the prime numbers less than or equal to the input of the user. Then finally giving a bool of true or false if the actual input of the user was a prime number.

```
            if (found)
            {
                vector_output.push_back(j);

            }
            if (number == j)
            {
                if (found ==false)
                    return false;
                else




void checkprime::vector_finder()    
{
    for (int k=0; k < vector_output.size(); k ++)
    {    
        cout << vector_output[k];
    }    
}
```

Unfortunately, my output is:

**User 3**

**Output 3**

**User 13**

**Output: 3 5 5 5 7 7 7 7 7 9 11 13**

How can I get it to where the vector does not duplicate numbers?

I thought something like an if statement right before the vector_output.pushback(j) such as

```
if (vector_output.size() != 0 && vector.output.back() != j)
      vector_output.push_back(j);
```

would work, but it's not outputting anything with this.

Comment: Unless you're intentionally making it as slow as possible, you really want to use the Sieve of Eratosthenes for this.

Comment: I'd like to be to stop my program from creating duplicates then I'll move on to efficiency. I'm still very much a beginner and I realize this may not be the best way to do things.

Comment: Just as a note on the topic - determining if a number is prime is a VERY hard task. You better be praying that people enter in small numbers.

Comment: @Mdjon26: When written (even close to) correctly, the sieve won't produce duplicates in the first place.

Comment: @Dgrin91: Given that it's being entered as an `int`, the task isn't difficult at all. Factoring becomes difficult for *large* numbers, but in a typical implementation that will only accept a dozen (or fewer) digits in an `int`, the task isn't all that tough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the duplicates using [`std::unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique). For example:

```
std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 9, 1};
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());

v.erase(std::unique(v.begin(), v.end()), v.end());
```

Comment: @Mdjon26 After you're done calculating the primes, do `std::unqiue(vector_output.begin(), vector_output.end());` and that should remove all duplicates in that range. This requires `#include <algorithm>`

Comment: I put it inside my void statement before I cout my vector and when I put in the number 13. it's outputting 3 5 7 9 11 13 7 7 7 9 11 13, which is really close, but for some reason it's repeating.

Comment: By itself, `std::unique` only squeezes the unique elements together. You still need to `erase` to make the container smaller.

Comment: How exactly would I erase them? I've never used the erase feature either :/. Seems like there should be an easier way to do this.

Comment: @Mdjon26 Please see the update. The only difference should be the variable names.

Comment: ...and the container must be ordered before using `std::unique`. Your example won't remove the trailing `1`.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Yes, another issue! Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Mdjon26 As Blastfurnace said, it's best to have your vector sorted first, so do `std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());`